# How to run ci/cd piple line with the previous commits in GITLLAB

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have committed the changed before yml file created. Now i want to run the ci/cd for old commits.

If i run the old job which is not considering the latest yml file changes. so again its failing the job.

Is it possible to run the run with the previous commited change in GIT HUB?

Comment: You will need to merge in your YML changes to your branch with the commits you want to release.

Comment: How to merge the previous commits with the same branch? @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Please provide a specific example of your commit history so that we can talk about concrete commands to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any functionality in Gitlab to "run pipeline on this commit". Generally it runs based off of new events (like new pushes, merge requests, and tags), and uses the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file present in the file structure for those events.

However, it should really matter though, since the file structure doesn't care about commits. Any changes you made previously are reflected in the current file structure. So once you add your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file and push, it will run the pipeline on the current file structure.